# Need help on layering

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, repository-pattern

I am trying to layer my WP app & following MVVM pattern. I have a VM with an ICommand which runs when a button is clicked on View. A click on button now runs a method as pointed by ICommand which retrieves data from DB using linq.

Here is how my VM looks.

```
public class CategoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Category type is a table in my DB. 
    private Category _currentCategory; 


    public Category CurrentCategory
        {
            get { return _currentCategory; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _currentCategory)
                {
                    _currentCategory = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCategory");
                }
            }
        }

// Helper method hooked with ICommand via RelayCommand class. 
// not posting RelayCommand class code here. 
private void GetCategory()
        {
            using (CategoryDBContext ctx = new CategoryDBContext(CategoryDBContext.ConnectionString))
            {
                CurrentCategory = ctx.Categories.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

}
```

Here is how my View looks.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentCategory.CategoryName}" />
<Button Command="{Binding GetCategoryCommand}" Content="Click me"/>
```

I am trying to implement a Implementing a Generic Repository and a Unit of Work Class & somewhat following ideas mentioned in [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article. If you scroll now a bit there to "Creating a Generic Repository" , you will find use of DbSet< TEntity > because they are using EF. What is equivalent of this in WP ?

How can i do something similar in WP app ? I don't want any data access code in my VM. Where should it go ? Also, the reason i want to Implement a Generic Repository is to avoid creating multiple repositories classes like CategoryRepositoy, ProductRepositoy etc.... 
I already have all POCO classes in place in my Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you would like to have a single repository for all your get/save methods? If you can do this with Windows Phone? and Where does it go because you don't want it in the VM?

Making a basic interface with a get and set, this is a good place to start
http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

The repository code doesnt need to be in the VM directly, but you should still call it from the vm.

View = ui, Model = data, view model = everything else such as getting/setting/updating/manipulating the data.